# Read Parquet file using pandas and change the datatype of a column while reading it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to read the data as Parquet file using pandas and change the datatype of a column while reading it.

```
import pandas as pd
product = pd.read_parquet('/datalake/test_usecase/products/')
```

Getting the error

> **ArrowInvalid: Failed to parse string:  as a scalar of type int64.**

The column which I read is of long type. How to cast the column as string while reading using pandas dataframe. Thanks in advance

Comment: could there be any columns with mixed `string` and `integer` types?

Comment: Which versions of pandas and pyarrow are you using?

Comment: pandas=1.5.3 pyarrow=11.0.0. This are the version, I am using. And there are columns with INT & String. In this case, how to read using pandas dataframe.

Comment: Is it okay with you to give us the sample input data.So that we can test it from our end and provide the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you know column names and their corresponding types, you can use [pyarrow.schema](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/3.0/python/generated/pyarrow.schema.html) in your reading parameters.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

schema = pa.schema([("column1", "string"), ("column2", "int64")])
df = pq.read_table("/datalake/test_usecase/products/", schema=schema).to_pandas()
```

I believe you can use same schema parameter on [pandas.read_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) function as well if you use pyarrow engine.